# load data to struct and display, c

Tags: c, struct

I am new to use C programming and trying to fill a structure and print the actual data stored in my struct. I'm stuck with `segfault`. see my sample code:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct full_data 
{
    char *first_name;               
    char *last_name;
    int *id_code;

};

struct owner 
{
    int *owner_code;
    struct full_data tdata;
};

void display_my_output(struct owner *mydata)
{
    printf("My data should be: \nfirst_name: %s\nlast_name: %s\nid_code: %d\nowner_id: %d\n",mydata->tdata.first_name ,mydata->tdata.last_name,mydata->tdata.id_code,mydata->owner_code);
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    struct owner *own;
    for(i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            own->tdata.first_name = "PAUL";
        }
        if(i==1)
        {
            own->tdata.last_name = "ROOT";
        }
        if(i==2)
        {
            own->tdata.id_code =30001;
        }
        if(i==3)
        {
            own->owner_code = 2*i;
        }
    }
    display_my_output(own);
    return 0;
}
```

Am expecting my out put as:

```
My data should be:
first_name: PAUL
last_name: ROOT
id_code: 30001
owner_id: 6
```

Do i miss something in my code?

Comment: `struct owner *own;` does not initialize the pointer. Using the value of this pointer is undefined behavior.

Comment: `struct owner *own;` → `struct owner data, *own = &data;` or `struct owner *own = malloc(sizeof *own); /* And After own's Use */ free(own);`

Comment: Enable warnings on your compiler.

Comment: @EOF: "undifined behaviour" , cant access any values? can you explain?

Comment: @kahsay.k: C11 draft standard n1570, `3. Terms, definitions, and symbols, 3.4.3 1 undefined behavior: behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are missing the fact that you declare and use a pointer to a `struct owner`, which means that you must initialize it.

So you could do

```
struct owner *own = calloc(1, sizeof(struct owner));
..
free(own);
```

but if you don't need to allocate it on heap then you could just allocate it on stack:

```
struct owner own;
own.tdata.first_name = ...;
```

Allocating it on the stack wouldn't prevent you from getting the address and pass it to `display_my_output` function. You just need to call it through `display_my_output(&own);`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize    `struct owner *own;` using `malloc()` like this:

`own = (struct owner*) malloc(sizeof(struct owner);`

and don't forget to free memory at the end:

`free(own);`

Also, in both your structs, you are making a  pointer to an integer rather than integer. I don't think you need an int*.

Answer (score 0):

`struct owner *own;` declares a pointer to `struct owner`. Yes, now the compiler knows that the object `own` points to is a `struct owner`, but which `struct owner` is it pointing to? The compiler didn't know, because you didn't tell it.

In fact, an uninitialised pointer may point to an invalid/unavailable memory address, or contain a "trap representation". The result of either of them is undefined behaviour, which causes `segfault` in your case.

To fix this, write

```
struct owner *own = malloc(sizeof(struct owner));
```

The call to `malloc()` allocates a block of memory to hold a `struct owner` to `own`; thus it'll be pointing to valid memory.

Also, don't forget to add `free(own)` before `main()` returns, or you will get a memory leak.